# Keras image captioning model generating the same caption for each mini batch respectively

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, vgg-net

I am using image features from a pretrained VGG network, and pretrained GloVe word embeddings. My architecture is as follows:

```
vgg16 = VGG16()

for i in range(len(vgg16.layers)):
  vgg16.layers[i].trainable = False

drop1 = Dropout(0.3)(vgg16.layers[-3].output)
vgg_out = Dense(256, activation="relu")(drop1)

inp = Input(shape=max_seq_length)
embedding = embedding_layer(inp)

lstm = LSTM(256)(embedding)
dense_last = add([vgg_out, lstm])
drop = Dropout(0.5)(dense_last)
outp = Dense(vocab_size, activation="softmax")(drop)

model = Model(inputs=[vgg16.inputs, inp], outputs=outp)
```

I am training it on mini batches of coupled images and captions, the problem that I really don't understand is that it generates the different captions for mini batches, where those captions are the same for each image inside a specific mini batch. Like:

```
# first mini batch
"a man in a blue and white dog is jumping over a ball."
"a man in a blue and white dog is jumping over a ball."
"a man in a blue and white dog is jumping over a ball."
...
# second mini batch
"a man in a red shirt is jumping over a grassy field."
"a man in a red shirt is jumping over a grassy field."
"a man in a red shirt is jumping over a grassy field."
...
# third mini batch
"a man in a blue shirt and black shirt and white pants is jumping on a field."
"a man in a blue shirt and black shirt and white pants is jumping on a field."
"a man in a blue shirt and black shirt and white pants is jumping on a field."
...
```

I get the themes are similar too, but how do I solve this problem? I've tried fine tuning the hyperparameters, and it is not working.

Comment: Try with VGG layers trainable=True so, that it can adapt as per your application.

Comment: @Mukul hey thanks for the tip, tried it and it doesn't change the results, besides of course, it also takes up a lot more time to train. I'll trust VGG's generalization for my problem on this one.